# What's the difference between .bashrc and /etc/bash.bashrc?

Tags: bash, bashrc

[image: .bashrc and /etc/bashrc]

What's the difference between `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: I don't see `/etc/bashrc` anywhere.

Comment: See bash's manpage section FILES.

Comment: @mikewhatever , you can find /etc/bash.bashrc .

Comment: @Cyrus I checked the man page FILES section and "bash.bashrc" doesn't appear there only "~/.bashrc" appears. Could you provide link to man page you were looking at? I was looking at [Bash Man Page](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html)

Comment: See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bash.1.html or `man bash`.

Comment: @Cyrus, I've found the answer from the link you've shared!

Comment: or `man --pager='less -p ^FILES' bash`

Answer (score 34):

When bash initializes a non-login interactive bash shell on a Debian/Ubuntu-like system, the shell first reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and then reads `~/.bashrc`.

The reason that `/etc/bash.bashrc` does not appear in normal bash documentation (such as [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) or [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)) is that it is a feature added by Debian and adopted by Ubuntu.  As Debian explains it ([readme.debian](https://sources.debian.net/src/bash/4.3-15/debian/README/)):

> 5. What is /etc/bash.bashrc? It doesn't seem to be documented.
>
> The Debian version of bash is compiled with a special option
> (`-DSYS_BASHRC`) that makes bash read `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`
> for interactive non-login shells. So, on Debian systems,
> `/etc/bash.bashrc` is to `~/.bashrc` as `/etc/profile` is to
> `~/.bash_profile`.

Thus, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is documented in the Debian and Ubuntu man pages but not in man pages from other distributions that do not support this feature.

#### Update: More distributions

`/etc/bash.bashrc` has been adopted beyond Debian circles as comments indicate its usage in distros like Arch Linux, MSYS2 and thereby Git Bash.

Comment: It's worth noting that the usage is spreading.  Git bash, based off of MSYS2, also has this convention.  It seems to be adopted to establish system level adaptations/configurations/standards.

Comment: [Archlinux also sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Invocation).

Comment: @legends2k Thank you for that.  I updated the answer to add Arch Linux.

Answer (score 5):

System wide initialization file `/etc/bash.bashrc` 
and the standard personal initialization file `~/.bashrc`
if the shell is interactivе.